# Returning node with minimum value in a binary search tree implemented with templates and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-search-tree, unique-ptr

I am trying to implement BST with `unique_ptr`. I want to return the **node** with the minimum value in BST. I know how to return the **minimum value** and I wrote the function for it but what if I want to return node? Is it possible with the classes I have?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class BinarySearchTree{
    struct TreeNode;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> spTreeNode;
    struct TreeNode{
        T data;
        spTreeNode  left;
        spTreeNode  right;
        TreeNode(const T & value):data(value),left(nullptr),right(nullptr){}
    };



    spTreeNode root;
    bool insert(spTreeNode &node);
    void print(const spTreeNode&) const ;
public:
    BinarySearchTree();
    void insert( const T & node);
    void print()const;
    T getMin();

};

template<class T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree():root(nullptr){}

template<class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::insert(const T & ref)
{
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> node(new TreeNode(ref));
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = std::move(node);
    } else {
        TreeNode* temp = root.get();
        TreeNode* prev = root.get();
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            prev = temp;
            if (temp->data < ref)
                temp = temp->right.get();
            else
                temp = temp->left.get();
        }
        if (prev->data < ref)
            prev->right = std::move(node);
        else
            prev->left = std::move(node);
    }
}


template<class T>
T BinarySearchTree<T>::getMin()
{
    TreeNode* temp = root.get();
    TreeNode *prev = nullptr;
    while (temp)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->left.get();
    }
    return prev->data;
}


int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree<int> bst;
    bst.insert(13);
    bst.insert(3);
    bst.insert(5);
    bst.insert(31);
    bst.insert(511);
    bst.insert(311);
    std::cout << bst.getMin(); // Works but what if I want to return the Node?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One other note:  `getMin()` will segfault on an empty BinarySearchTree.  One way to handle that is to provide a member function `bool empty() const` and document to users that they must call `getMin()` only for a non-empty tree.  Same situation as `front()` accessor in `std::vector`, for example.

Comment: @NicholasM, yes good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to decide the interface you want.  Do you want to return a const pointer to the extant TreeNode?  A const reference to the TreeNode?  A copy of the TreeNode?  The key is to think about how long references/pointers will be valid.

I frankly don't think any of those are good ideas for a public interface.  So let's say you made `getMinNode()` private, and kept `getMin()` public:

```
// Returns non-owning pointer; do not attempt to delete TreeNode.
template<class T>
const BinarySearchTree<T>::TreeNode* BinarySearchTree<T>::getMinNode() const
{
    // Like getMin(), but return prev
    // Does this work for empty BinarySearchTree?
    TreeNode* temp = root.get();
    TreeNode *prev = nullptr;
    while (temp)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->left.get();
    }
    return prev;
}

template<class T>
T BinarySearchTree<T>::getMin() const   // member function is const
{
    return getMinNode()->data;
}
```

Comment: So, I should not return Node from public interface perspective?

Comment: @IanMcGrath Your Node is an internal implementation detail of your tree. Why would you want to return it?

Comment: I don't think you gain anything from returning to public users the min value of type `T` (that is, `data`) plus two smart pointers, one or both of which is empty.

Comment: @T.C. (reminds me of Top Cat, anyway, I digress), I thought so too. Just wanted to know if there is any way in case I do have to do it. It is online test and I might have to write code according to set interfaces (which I do not know now).

Comment: @NicholasM , if returning minimum value is not OK and so is minimum node, how do I go about returning minimum <node|value|thing> ?

Comment: I think that returning the minimum value (of type `T`) with your original `getMin()` function is a good part of the public interface.  (Subject to changes mentioned above: make member function `const` and decide how to handle empty BinarySearchTree.)

I showed how to mechanically return the node, while keeping `getMin()` as part of the public interface.  This seems like a bit of an [X/Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem); why do you want to return the min node?

Comment: @NicholasM , yes it is a X|Y problem. But I got what I was looking for. Thanks.